# Swift, Load UIViewController With Code

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to load `UIViewController` from `Main.StoryBoard`

**Example Code in C# :**

```
Form2 f2 = new From2();
f2.Show();
```

But I don't know how to do this with swift?

**example :**

```
viewDidLoad()
{
    var model = UIDevice.currentDevice().model

    if (model == "iPhone 6")
    {
        ViewController_iPhone6.LoadView
    }
}
```

Like This Code ^
Something Like This

Comment: Do you mean you need to do right at the beginning of the app? 
or when inside the firstViewController?

Comment: idk wich one just i want to load view 

edit : Read My Example Code Please